# Can I call an arm64 Process using BuildProcess in Java?

Tags: java, apple-m1, arm64, processbuilder, rosetta

I am trying to call some terminal commands from Java using the Java ProcessBuilder with an ***M1 Mac*** that uses arm64. However, even though that I am using ***arm64*** compatible JVM (Zulu 11, 17..) that identify arm64 chips, whenever I try to use the Java ProcessBuilder, it seems that the terminal is using ***Rosetta***.

For example, the following command returns `x86_64` instead of the expected `arm64`.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.command(new String[] {"bash", "-c", "uname -m"});
Process proc = pb.start();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
String text = "";
String line;
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
     text += line + System.lineSeparator();
}
bufferedReader.close();
System.out.println(text);
```

Do you know if there is any ***other way to execute terminal commands from Java*** using acutally the arm64 chip instead of the emulated Intel one?

Regards,

Carlos

Comment: Can you try `pb.command(new String[] {"/usr/bin/uname", "-m"});`

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this on my M1 Pro. It prints `arm64` as expected. I did have to change `input` to `bufferedReader` in the code provided. Was that just a transcription error or is it actually reading the wrong thing in your original code?

Answer (score 3):

By default, any process will inherit the architecture of the process that spawned it (if a slice for that architecture is available in the binary).

If the processes you're spawning from Java are running as x86_64, then that indicates that your Java process is running as x86_64, and if you did not explicitly invoke it as such, it further indicates that your shell, terminal, IDE or whatever you spawned it from, is also running as x86_64.

On the syscall layer, this behaviour can be overridden with Apple's proprietary `posix_spawnattr_setbinpref_np()` to select the preferred architecture slice in universal binaries when using `posix_spawn()`.

On the command line, this is supported via the `arch` command:

```
arch -arm64 uname -m
arch -x86_64 uname -m
```

So in your code, this should look like this:

```
{"arch", "-arm64", "bash", "-c", "uname -m"}
```

You can also pass multiple architecture selectors to the `arch` command to be attempted in that order, so if you want your code to spawn native binaries whenever possible on either arm64 or x86_64 hosts, you can use:

```
{"arch", "-arm64", "-x86_64", "bash", "-c", "uname -m"}
```