# Why does Python CDLL() on mac M1 requires x86_64 lib?

Tags: python, macos, x86-64, arm64

I try to use TDlib JSON API with CDLL() on Mac M1 using Python 3.8.

The following code:

```
from ctypes import *
file = '/Users/thej/td/tdlib/lib/libtdjson.dylib'
tdfunctions = CDLL(file)
```

produces this error:

```
OSError: dlopen(/Users/thej/td/tdlib/lib/libtdjson.dylib, 0x0006): tried: '/Users/thej/td/tdlib/lib/libtdjson.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')),
 '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/thej/td/tdlib/lib/libtdjson.dylib' (no such file),
 '/Users/thej/td/tdlib/lib/libtdjson.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')),
 '/Users/thej/td/tdlib/lib/libtdjson.1.8.16.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')),
 '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/thej/td/tdlib/lib/libtdjson.1.8.16.dylib' (no such file), 
'/Users/thej/td/tdlib/lib/libtdjson.1.8.16.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
```

So, the question is: why CDLL() asks for x86_64 libs on clearly Arm64 system? Is my Python installation wrong?

PS: Similar questions answers suggest fixes, but not explain what's happening here.

Solved: I actually had x86_64 python installed for no particular reason. Installed arm64 version, code above runs fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I call an arm64 Process using BuildProcess in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74425642/can-i-call-an-arm64-process-using-buildprocess-in-java)

Comment: How are you running Python?  Is it from an x86-64 process?

Comment: @PeterCordes I run the code as scratch from pycharm. Pycharm itself is marked as Apple in the Activity Monitor, but Python i run from it is Intel. That's kinda strange.

Comment: @Siguza not entirely. I understood the inheritance of arch in the processes, but no idea why Python I run is x86_64

Comment: Problem solved, thanks for the insights!